# Group from Array to Dictionary

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, grouping

I have class:

```
class DisplayTime {

    var time: Schedules

    init (time: Schedules){
        self.time = time

    }
}
```

`Schedules` - class with next properties:

```
class Schedules: Object {
    dynamic var hour = 0
    dynamic var minute = 0
    dynamic var groupIndex = 0

}
```

So, I'd like to get `Dictionary`, where key - hour, and value - array of `Schedules` - `var dictTime: [Int:[Schedules]]`

I try, but unsuccessfully:

```
func groupBy() -> [Int:[Schedules]]{

        let displayTime = self.displayTimes

        var dictTime: [Int:[Schedules]] = [:]


        for i in 0..<displayTime.count {

            dictTime[displayTime[i].time.hour] = [displayTime[i].time]
        }

       print (dictTime)

      return dictTime

    }
```

I understand - that function created only [key:[one_value]], but I may have several values for one key, how to handle that variant? (if key_now repeat key_before -> add to array Schedules for key_now to key_before.

Comment: See [How to group by the elements of an array in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31220002/2976878)

Comment: Last user with excelent winterbash hat :-)

Comment: @Hamish, yes, I saw it, but i can't use that example in my function((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `categorise(_:)` method from [the extension shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39388832/2976878), you can simply say:

```
let dictTime = displayTimes.lazy.map{$0.time}.categorise{$0.hour}
```

`map(_:)` is used in order to iterate over the `time` of each `DisplayTime` and `lazy` is used in order to prevent the creation of an intermediate array.