# Group elements with the same property value from an array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have an array **[modelA,modelB,modelC,modelD,modelE]**, each element in the array is an instance of a Struct. The Struct has a property "name". for example...

```
modelA.name = "abc"
modelB.name = "efg" 
modelC.name = "hij"    
modelD.name = "abc"
modelE.name = "efg"
```

How can I group elements with the same property value into a new array? i.e. **put modelA and modelD into a new array,and put modelB and modelE into another array**.

Assume the original array is **large**.

Comment: What would be wrong with `var d[String: [Model]]; for i in array { let m = array.filter { $0.name == i.name }; if m.count > 1 { d[i.name] = m }}`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31220002/how-to-group-by-the-elements-of-an-array-in-swift this solve my question, thanks for everyone

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using [filter(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1688383-filter):

> Returns an array containing, in order, the elements of the sequence
>   that satisfy the given predicate.

For example, consider that the structure looks like:

```
struct Model {
    var name: String?
}
```

And you have an array of models:

```
let allModelsArray = [Model(name: "abc"), Model(name: "efg"), Model(name: "hij"), Model(name: "abc"), Model(name: "efg"), Model(name: "efg"), Model(name: "hij")]
```

So, you can get your arrays by doing (assuming that you want to filter based on the value of the `name`):

```
let abcModelsArray = allModelsArray.filter { $0.name == "abc" }
// [Model(name: Optional("abc")), Model(name: Optional("abc"))]

let hijModelsArray = allModelsArray.filter { $0.name == "hij" }
// [Model(name: Optional("hij")), Model(name: Optional("hij"))]
```

*ALSO:*

You mentioned that:

> how can I put element which has the same property value into a new
>   array, such as put modelA and modelD into a new array, and put modelB
>   and modelE into a new array, **if array is large**.

Somehow, you might want to use the [lazy](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1782542-lazy) version of the collection.

Hope this helped.

Comment: For this you would have to know all the names to begin with. This would be O(n^2) at best. I think @Grimxn comment is a better solution for this and it would be O(n).

Comment: @Fogmeister - thanks for the comment, but mine is still O(n^2) as `filter` itself is O(n), multiplied by the `for` loop...

Comment: @Grimxn I meant the comment you left. Didn't see your answer. :-) oh. Also, I misread your comment :-)

Answer (score 2):

I have not performance tested this

```
struct Model {
    var type : String
    var name : String
}
var modelA = Model(type: "A", name: "abc")
var modelB = Model(type: "B", name: "efg")
var modelC = Model(type: "C", name: "abc")
var modelD = Model(type: "D", name: "efg")

let models = [modelA,modelB,modelC,modelD]

let names = Set(models.map({return $0.name}))

var groupedModels : [String:[Model]] = [:]
for var name in names {
    let elements = models.filter({$0.name == name})
    groupedModels[name] = elements
}
```

Comment: The good part of your answer that you are assuming that the `name` is unknown, which I find it more logical.

Answer (score 1):

`.reduce` solution:

```
let a = [modelA, modelB, modelC, modelD, modelE]

let arr = a.reduce([:]) { (result, currentModel) -> [String: [Model]] in
    var mutableDic = result
    if ((mutableDic[currentModel.name]) != nil) {
        mutableDic[currentModel.name]?.append(currentModel)
    } else {
        mutableDic[currentModel.name] = [currentModel]
    }

    return mutableDic
}
```

It will return the same dictionary as @Grimxn response. or got from this `for loop`

```
var mutableDic = [String : [Model]]()

        for aModel in a {
            if ((mutableDic[aModel.name]) != nil) {
                mutableDic[aModel.name]?.append(aModel)
            } else {
                mutableDic[aModel.name] = [aModel]
            }
        }
```

The key is to use a Dictionary to track for Model that need to be put in the same array, by comparing to it's `.name`.

Comment: This seems to be a better candidate than mine, as at first look it is O(n).

Comment: Nit picking, but it doesn't exactly return the same as mine, as mine only includes names multiply referenced...