# Get the Value of same keys

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I am in trouble in making the  array of dictionary. I need

```
["1.0" : [Park_N_Tap.GasStationList,Park_N_Tap.GasStationList,Park_N_Tap.GasStationList], "2.0" : [Park_N_Tap.GasStationList,Park_N_Tap.GasStationList,Park_N_Tap.GasStationList], "3.0" : [Park_N_Tap.GasStationList,Park_N_Tap.GasStationList,Park_N_Tap.GasStationList]]
```

form this

```
 [["1.0": Park_N_Tap.GasStationList], ["1.0": Park_N_Tap.GasStationList], ["1.0": Park_N_Tap.GasStationList], ["1.0": Park_N_Tap.GasStationList], ["1.0": Park_N_Tap.GasStationList], ["1.0": Park_N_Tap.GasStationList], ["1.0": Park_N_Tap.GasStationList], ["1.0": Park_N_Tap.GasStationList], ["1.0": Park_N_Tap.GasStationList], ["1.0": Park_N_Tap.GasStationList], ["1.0": Park_N_Tap.GasStationList], ["2.0": Park_N_Tap.GasStationList], ["2.0": Park_N_Tap.GasStationList], ["2.0": Park_N_Tap.GasStationList], ["2.0": Park_N_Tap.GasStationList], ["2.0": Park_N_Tap.GasStationList], ["2.0": Park_N_Tap.GasStationList], ["2.0": Park_N_Tap.GasStationList]]
```

Please suggest me sweet and suitable answer.

Comment: What you need is dictionary not array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to group by the elements of an array in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31220002/how-to-group-by-the-elements-of-an-array-in-swift)

Comment: @NiravD I need array of dictionary. Can you please suggest me way how can i do??

Comment: @AmritTiwari The desired output that you mention is not **Array of dictionary** but it is **Dictionary**

Comment: @NiravD sry my bad, How can i get that data? I have to implement it in table view and keys have to implement in section header and value in row. please help me

Comment: @AmritTiwari Have you checked linked provided by MartinR

Comment: @NiravD Yes brother but m not getting that answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let from = [["1.0": "Park_N_Tap.GasStationList"], ["1.0": "Park_N_Tap.GasStationList"], ["1.0": "Park_N_Tap.GasStationList"], ["1.0": "Park_N_Tap.GasStationList"], ["1.0": "Park_N_Tap.GasStationList"], ["1.0": "Park_N_Tap.GasStationList"], ["1.0": "Park_N_Tap.GasStationList"], ["1.0": "Park_N_Tap.GasStationList"], ["1.0": "Park_N_Tap.GasStationList"], ["1.0": "Park_N_Tap.GasStationList"], ["1.0": "Park_N_Tap.GasStationList"], ["2.0": "Park_N_Tap.GasStationList"], ["2.0": "Park_N_Tap.GasStationList"], ["2.0": "Park_N_Tap.GasStationList"], ["2.0": "Park_N_Tap.GasStationList"], ["2.0": "Park_N_Tap.GasStationList"], ["2.0": "Park_N_Tap.GasStationList"], ["2.0": "Park_N_Tap.GasStationList"]]

var to = [String:[String]]()

from.forEach { (dic) in
    dic.forEach({ (key,value) in
        var tempArray = to[key] ?? [String]()
        tempArray.append(value)
        to[key] = tempArray
    })
}
```

'to' is the result of you eventually need to, I don't know what Park_N_Tap.GasStationList, so I use string to show you see

[String:[String]] is out-of-order ,if you need order Array  you can try

```
var to = from.reduce(NSMutableDictionary()) { (result, dic) -> NSMutableDictionary in
    dic.forEach({ (key,value) in
        var tempArray = result[key] as? [String] ?? [String]()
        tempArray.append(value)
        result[key] = tempArray
    })
    return result
    }.sorted(by: {($0.0.key as! String) < ($0.1.key as! String)})
```

Comment: Thanks you :), You save my time.

Answer (score 0):

try this code :-

```
var dummyData: [String :[Any]] =  ["1.0" : ["Park_N_Tap.GasStationList","Park_N_Tap.GasStationList","Park_N_Tap.GasStationList"], "2.0" : ["Park_N_Tap.GasStationList","Park_N_Tap.GasStationList","Park_N_Tap.GasStationList"], "3.0" : ["Park_N_Tap.GasStationList","Park_N_Tap.GasStationList","Park_N_Tap.GasStationList"]]
var newArray: [[String:Any]] = []
for eachItem in dummyData{
    var temp = [String:Any]()
    for eachValue in eachItem.value{
    var temp = [String:Any]()
    temp = [eachItem.key : eachValue]
        print(temp)
        newArray.append(temp)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry I was mistaken about conditions and results you can try this

```
let from = ["1.0" : ["Park_N_Tap.GasStationList","Park_N_Tap.GasStationList","Park_N_Tap.GasStationList"], "2.0" : ["Park_N_Tap.GasStationList","Park_N_Tap.GasStationList","Park_N_Tap.GasStationList"], "3.0" : ["Park_N_Tap.GasStationList","Park_N_Tap.GasStationList","Park_N_Tap.GasStationList"]]

var to = [[String:Any]]()

from.forEach { (key,value) in
    value.forEach({ (value1) in
        to.append([key:value])
    })
}
```