# Counting occurrences of items in a collection

Tags: ios, swift

I'm looking for a way to count how many times the same **product** is added to an **order** (I'm new to Swift)

```
struct Product {
  var name: String
  var price: Double
}

struct Order {
  var productsSold: [Product] = []
}

currentOrder = Order()
currentOrder.productsSold.append(products[1]) //From a JSON object "products"
currentOrder.productsSold.append(products[1])
currentOrder.productsSold.append(products[2])
currentOrder.productsSold.append(products[4])
```

I want to have to following result but I can't find a way to do it:

```
currentOrder.list() --> product_1 x2 // product_2 x1 // product_4 x1
```

I can only list all the products with:

```
//Inside struc Order
func listProductsSold() {
  if productsSold.count>0 {
    for product in productsSold {
      product.printProduct()
    }
  }
}
//Inside struc Product
func printProduct() {
    print("Nom: \(name), price: \(price), couleur: \(color)")
}
```

And then:

```
currentOrder.listProductsSold()

//Which give:
//Nom: Menu cheese, price: 17.0, couleur: rgb(247, 171, 56)
//Nom: Menu cheese, price: 17.0, couleur: rgb(247, 171, 56)
//Nom: Rouge n1, price: 18.0, couleur: rgb(166, 77, 121)
//Nom: Vin vigneron, price: 22.0, couleur: rgb(166, 77, 121)
```

Comment: You could use counted set, example from Hacking with swift:

var spaceships = ["Serenity", "Nostromo", "Enterprise"]
spaceships += ["Voyager", "Serenity", "Star Destroyer"]
spaceships += ["Galactica", "Sulaco", "Minbari"]
let countedSet = NSCountedSet(array: spaceships)
print(countedSet.count(for: "Serenity")) // 2
print(countedSet.count(for: "Sulaco")) // 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a simple solution to count the number of products sold per order, using a dictionary with the product name and a count:

```
        var productsCount = [String: Int]()

        for product in currentOrder.productsSold {
            if let countedProduct = productsCount[product.name] {
                productsCount[product.name] =  productsCount[product.name]! + 1
            } else {
                productsCount[product.name] = 1
            }
        }
```

**Edit**

Example modified to use `Product` instead of a `String` as the dictionary key.

First change `Product` to implement the `Hashable` and `Equatable` protocols:

```
struct Product: Hashable {
    var name: String
    var price: Double

    var hashValue: Int {
        get {
            return self.name.hashValue
        }
    }

    static func ==(lhs: Product, rhs: Product) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name == rhs.name
    }
}
```

Then change the type in the key dictionary to `Product`:

```
var productsCount = [Product: Int]()

for product in currentOrder.productsSold {
    if let countedProduct = productsCount[product] {
        productsCount[product] =  productsCount[product]! + 1
    } else {
        productsCount[product] = 1
    }
}
```

Comment: An NSCountedSet would be simpler.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Now, if I need each product with its count, how can I do that? Let's say I need: "product.name, product.color, product.price, … , productCount

Answer (score 2):

You first need a "group by" function to collect all identical products into an array. An example of such function can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31220067/2538939)

```
public extension Sequence {
    func group<U: Hashable>(by key: (Iterator.Element) -> U) -> [U:[Iterator.Element]] {
        var categories: [U: [Iterator.Element]] = [:]
        for element in self {
            let key = key(element)
            if case nil = categories[key]?.append(element) {
                categories[key] = [element]
            }
        }
        return categories
    }
}
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
let orderSummary = currentOrder.productsSold
                        .group  { $0.name }
                        .sorted { $0.key < $1.key  }
                        .map    { "\($0.key) x \($0.value.count)" }
                        .joined(separator: ", ")
```

What it does:

- `.group` groups the `productSolds` into a dictionary, whose key is the product name and value is an array of products having the same name.
- `.sorted` sorts the collection of key-value pairs by the key (i.e. the product name)
- `.map` builds a summary string for each product, in the template of `product_name x count`
- `.joined` concatenates these strings into an overall order summary.