# Grouping json objects if object contains duplicate name based on key?

Tags: ios, swift3, collections, swift4

We are having array of json objects like below:

```
[{
    "CompanyCode": "1",
    "MachineCode": null,
    "MachineName": null,
    "NoOfMeters": null,
    "ScheduleNo": "12028",
    "ScheduleDate": "17/2/2018 12:00:00 AM",
    "ScheduleUser": "sales",
    "CustomerCode": "0022100007",
    "DeliveryCode": "0",
    "SortOrder": "1",
    "JobRefNo": "",
    "CustomerName": "COLD STORAGE SUPERMARKETS ",
    "CustAddress1": "GIANT COMPLEX",
    "OutletName": "",
    "OutAddress1": "",
    "IsJobClosed": ""
}, {
    "CompanyCode": "1",
    "MachineCode": null,
    "MachineName": null,
    "NoOfMeters": null,
    "ScheduleNo": "12029",
    "ScheduleDate": "17/2/2018 12:00:00 AM",
    "ScheduleUser": "sales",
    "CustomerCode": "0022100008",
    "DeliveryCode": "0",
    "SortOrder": "1",
    "JobRefNo": "",
    "CustomerName": "COLD STORAGE WH - 21 TAMPINES ",
    "CustAddress1": "GIANT COMPLEX",
    "OutletName": "",
    "OutAddress1": "",
    "IsJobClosed": ""
}, {
    "CompanyCode": "1",
    "MachineCode": null,
    "MachineName": null,
    "NoOfMeters": null,
    "ScheduleNo": "12027",
    "ScheduleDate": "17/2/2018 12:00:00 AM",
    "ScheduleUser": "winapp",
    "CustomerCode": "0022100003",
    "DeliveryCode": "0",
    "SortOrder": "1",
    "JobRefNo": "",
    "CustomerName": "AVENZA PTE LTD ",
    "CustAddress1": "83 CLEMENCEAU AVE",
    "OutletName": "",
    "OutAddress1": "",
    "IsJobClosed": ""
}, {
    "CompanyCode": "1",
    "MachineCode": null,
    "MachineName": null,
    "NoOfMeters": null,
    "ScheduleNo": "12025",
    "ScheduleDate": "17/2/2018 12:00:00 AM",
    "ScheduleUser": "winapp",
    "CustomerCode": "0022100001",
    "DeliveryCode": "0",
    "SortOrder": "1",
    "JobRefNo": "",
    "CustomerName": "CASH ON DELIVERY (TO) ",
    "CustAddress1": "CASH ON DELIVERY",
    "OutletName": "",
    "OutAddress1": "",
    "IsJobClosed": ""
}, {
    "CompanyCode": "1",
    "MachineCode": null,
    "MachineName": null,
    "NoOfMeters": null,
    "ScheduleNo": "12026",
    "ScheduleDate": "17/2/2018 12:00:00 AM",
    "ScheduleUser": "winapp",
    "CustomerCode": "0022100002",
    "DeliveryCode": "0",
    "SortOrder": "1",
    "JobRefNo": "",
    "CustomerName": "DESPATCH - MT ",
    "CustAddress1": "DESPATCH",
    "OutletName": "",
    "OutAddress1": "",
    "IsJobClosed": ""
}]
```

We wanted group this array based on **ScheduleUser** key like section.

```
[
  "Sales":[
            {

            }
            {

            }

           ]
  "winapp":[
            {

                }
            {

                }

            {

            }

            ]
  ]
```

We have studied about grouping in swift 4 [Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2919592-init)

But they given with array of string, we don't have idea to working json values.
Kindly give us solution if any other way. we have referred following [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31220002/how-to-group-by-the-elements-of-an-array-in-swift)

We are not able to understand this.

Getting values from local

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "salesorder", ofType: "json") {
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .alwaysMapped)
            do{
                let json =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)
                let jsonDictionary =  json as? [[String:Any]]

                print(jsonDictionary!)

            }catch let error{
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    } else {
        print("Invalid filename/path.")
    }
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: how are you parsing this json?

Comment: I added this json as file in bundle path

Comment: Please post the code. I will advice you to get all possible `ScheduleUser` (as array) and later `filter` out data for each `ScheduleUser` value.

Comment: @HarvantS.Choudhary Thanks for reply, Can you pls add some sample code or ling?

Comment: I am not good in swift but sure will try.

Comment: okay let me search on it

Comment: Check the answer. That should work.

Comment: Check my answer @KarthiKeyan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Better

**Using grouping way**

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "salesorder", ofType: "json") {
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .alwaysMapped)
            do{
                let json =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)
                if let jsonDictionary =  json as? [[String:Any]]{
                
                var grouped2 : [String:[[String:Any]]] = Dictionary(grouping: jsonDictionary, by: {$0["ScheduleUser"] as! String})
                debugPrint(grouped2)
                print(jsonDictionary)
                }
                
            }catch let error{
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    } else {
        print("Invalid filename/path.")
    }
```

**Manual way**

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "salesorder", ofType: "json") {
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .alwaysMapped)
                do{
                    let json =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)
                    if let jsonDictionary =  json as? [[String:Any]]{
                    
                        var grouped : [String:[[String:Any]]] = [:]
                        for dict in jsonDictionary {
                            let value = dict["ScheduleUser"] as! String
                            if(grouped[dict["ScheduleUser"] as! String] == nil){
                                grouped[value] = [dict]
                            }else{
                                grouped[value]?.append(dict)
                            }
                        }
                        debugPrint(grouped)
                    print(jsonDictionary)
                    }
                    
                }catch let error{
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            } catch let error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        } else {
            print("Invalid filename/path.")
        }
```

**Log**

> ["winapp": [["MachineName": , "CustomerCode": 0022100003,
> "JobRefNo": , "OutAddress1": , "SortOrder": 1, "IsJobClosed": ,
> "CustAddress1": 83 CLEMENCEAU AVE, "OutletName": , "MachineCode":
> , "ScheduleDate": 17/2/2018 12:00:00 AM, "CustomerName": AVENZA
> PTE LTD , "ScheduleNo": 12027, "NoOfMeters": , "DeliveryCode":
> 0, "ScheduleUser": winapp, "CompanyCode": 1], ["MachineName": ,
> "CustomerCode": 0022100001, "JobRefNo": , "OutAddress1": ,
> "SortOrder": 1, "IsJobClosed": , "CustAddress1": CASH ON DELIVERY,
> "OutletName": , "MachineCode": , "ScheduleDate": 17/2/2018
> 12:00:00 AM, "CustomerName": CASH ON DELIVERY (TO) , "ScheduleNo":
> 12025, "NoOfMeters": , "DeliveryCode": 0, "ScheduleUser":
> winapp, "CompanyCode": 1], ["MachineName": , "CustomerCode":
> 0022100002, "JobRefNo": , "OutAddress1": , "SortOrder": 1,
> "IsJobClosed": , "CustAddress1": DESPATCH, "OutletName": ,
> "MachineCode": , "ScheduleDate": 17/2/2018 12:00:00 AM,
> "CustomerName": DESPATCH - MT , "ScheduleNo": 12026, "NoOfMeters":
> , "DeliveryCode": 0, "ScheduleUser": winapp, "CompanyCode": 1]],
> "sales": [["MachineName": , "CustomerCode": 0022100007,
> "JobRefNo": , "OutAddress1": , "SortOrder": 1, "IsJobClosed": ,
> "CustAddress1": GIANT COMPLEX, "OutletName": , "MachineCode": ,
> "ScheduleDate": 17/2/2018 12:00:00 AM, "CustomerName": COLD STORAGE
> SUPERMARKETS , "ScheduleNo": 12028, "NoOfMeters": ,
> "DeliveryCode": 0, "ScheduleUser": sales, "CompanyCode": 1],
> ["MachineName": , "CustomerCode": 0022100008, "JobRefNo": ,
> "OutAddress1": , "SortOrder": 1, "IsJobClosed": , "CustAddress1":
> GIANT COMPLEX, "OutletName": , "MachineCode": , "ScheduleDate":
> 17/2/2018 12:00:00 AM, "CustomerName": COLD STORAGE WH - 21 TAMPINES ,
> "ScheduleNo": 12029, "NoOfMeters": , "DeliveryCode": 0,
> "ScheduleUser": sales, "CompanyCode": 1]]]

Answer (score 1):

Get all possible values in an array -

```
let arr = your data...
let posValues = arr.map { $0["ScheduleUser"] as? String }
```

Now create a dictionary for filter data -

```
var newDict:[String:Any] = [:]

for aValue in posValues {

    let filteredDicts = arr.filter({ ($0.["ScheduleUser"] == aValue)})
    newDict[aValue] = filteredDicts
}
```

Comment: i am getting error on  let posValues = arr.map { $0["ScheduleUser"] as? String }

Cannot subscript a value of type '[[String : Any]]' with an index of type 'String'

Comment: there was a mistake. fixed the answer.