# How to get grouped array of struct in swift 4?

Tags: ios, multidimensional-array, swift4, higher-order-functions

I have an array of structs in which ingredientId can be same for two or more elements. Code for the same is as below:

```
struct Cart {
    var bundleId: Int = 0
    var ingredientId: Int = 0
}

var array:[Cart] = []
array.append(Cart(bundleId: 1, ingredientId: 1))
array.append(Cart(bundleId: 2, ingredientId: 2))
array.append(Cart(bundleId: 3, ingredientId: 2))
array.append(Cart(bundleId: 4, ingredientId: 5))
array.append(Cart(bundleId: 5, ingredientId: 5))
array.append(Cart(bundleId: 6, ingredientId: 6))
print(array)
```

What I am expecting as output is an array with elements grouped according to same ingredientId e.g.

> ```
> [
>    [Cart(bundleId: 1, ingredientId: 1)],
>    [Cart(bundleId: 2, ingredientId: 2),Cart(bundleId: 3, ingredientId: 2)],
>    [Cart(bundleId: 4, ingredientId: 5),Cart(bundleId: 5, ingredientId: 5)],
>    [Cart(bundleId: 6, ingredientId: 6)],
>    ............
>    .......
> ]
> ```

P.S.: ingredientId's are not fixed and we don't have separate array for them.

How to achieve this using Higher order functions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31220002/how-to-group-by-the-elements-of-an-array-in-swift ?

Comment: @Larme: this helped me a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can used the `grouped` API exposed by the `Dictionary` to transform your array in to a dictionary of `Carts` grouped by `ingredientId`;

```
let groupedDictionary = Dictionary(grouping: array) { $0.ingredientId }
```

If you then need to transform that Dictionary in to an Array;

```
let twoDimensionalArray = groupedDictionary.map { $0.value }
```