# Is it possible to return Fluent children in a GET request?

Tags: mysql, swift, vapor

Right now I have the following two classes:

```
final class Song: MySQLModel {
    var id: Int?
    var lyrics: String
    var artist: String
    var title: String
    var strummingPattern: String

    init(id: Int? = nil, title: String, lyrics: String, artist: String, strummingPattern: String) {

        self.id = id
        self.lyrics = lyrics
        self.title = title
        self.artist = artist
        self.strummingPattern = strummingPattern

    }
}

extension Song {
    var chords: Children<Song, SongChord>{
        return children(\.songID)
    }
}

final class SongChord: MySQLModel {
    var id: Int?
    var songID: Int
    var chord: String
    var position: Int

    init(id: Int? = nil, chord: String, position: Int, songID: Int) {
        self.songID = songID
        self.id = id
        self.chord = chord
        self.position = position
    }
}

extension SongChord {
    var chords: Parent<SongChord, Song>{
        return parent(\.songID)
    }
}
```

I want to return a list of all `Song`s with their respective `SongChord` children. So far I've come up with:

```
return Song.query(on: req)
            .join(\SongChord.songID, to: \Song.id)
            .alsoDecode(SongChord.self)
            .all()
```

But this returns an error of "Cannot convert value of type 'EventLoopFuture<[(Song, SongChord)]>' to closure result type '_'". Some people online were suggesting doing a flatmap, but this was still producing an error. Any suggestions on how to retrieve the children would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As the error implies you return `EventLoopFuture<[(Song, SongChord)]>`. If you decode multiple models from your `query result`, you will receive a Tupel of `Song` and `SongChord` for each result row; what you have to do now is:

1. Create a struct (e.g. `SongViewModel`) that conforms to `Content` and has all relevant fields from `Song` and another var called `chords: [SongChords]`. Reason is, the original `Song` model has no array of `SongChord` but only a `Children<Song, SongChord>` which you cannot resolve easily
2. `Map` your result from `[(Song, SongChord)]` to `[SongViewModel]`. This might be of help for you to transform your Tuple array: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31220067/710350
3. return `[SongViewModel]`