# Filter items to section

Tags: swift

I want to filter items with property `isCompleted = true` to section with name Completed and non completed items to ToDo. How to render items?

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0 {
            return manager.tasks.filter({$0.isCompleted == false}).count
        } else {
            return manager.tasks.filter({$0.isCompleted}).count
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        switch section {
        case 0:
            return "ToDo"
        case 1:
            return "Completed"
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Keys.cell.rawValue, for: indexPath) as! ToDoCell

        let currentItem = manager.tasks[indexPath.row]
        cell.titleLabel.text = currentItem.taskName
        cell.descriptionLabel.text = currentItem.description
        if manager.tasks[indexPath.row].description?.isEmpty ?? false {
            cell.descLabelBottomConstraint.constant = 0
        }

        let accessoryType: UITableViewCell.AccessoryType = currentItem.isCompleted ? .checkmark : .none
        cell.accessoryType = accessoryType
        return cell
    }
```

I guess I need to filter items into two different arrays? But which way is the most correct?

Comment: `let currentItem = manager.tasks[indexPath.row]` is the problem. You are failing to distinguish completed items. The entire data model itself is wrong. A single simple array won’t work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never filter things in `numberOfRowsInSection`. Don't do that, this method is called very often.

- Create a model

  ```
  struct Section {
      let title : String
      var items : [Task]
  }
  ```
- Declare the data source array

  ```
  var sections = [Section]()
  ```
- In `viewDidLoad` populate the array and reload the table view

  ```
  sections = [Section(title: "ToDo", items: manager.tasks.filter{!$0.isCompleted}),
              Section(title: "Completed", items: manager.tasks.filter{$0.isCompleted})]
  tableView.reloadData()
  ```
- Now the datasource methods become very clean (and fast)

  ```
  override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
      return sections.count
  }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return sections[section].items.count
  }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
      return sections[section].title
  }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Keys.cell.rawValue, for: indexPath) as! ToDoCell

      let currentItem = sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]
      cell.titleLabel.text = currentItem.taskName
      cell.descriptionLabel.text = currentItem.description
      if currentItem.description?.isEmpty ?? false {
          cell.descLabelBottomConstraint.constant = 0
      } // you have to add an else clause to set the constraint to the default value

      cell.accessoryType = currentItem.isCompleted ? .checkmark : .none
      return cell
  }
  ```

It would be still more efficient to filter the items O(n) with a partition algorithm

```
let p = manager.tasks.partition(by: { $0.completed })
sections = [Section(title: "ToDo", items: Array(manager.tasks[p...])),
            Section(title: "Completed", items: Array(manager.tasks[..<p]))]
tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range.
In titleForHeaderInSection

Comment: Of course you have to adjust `numberOfSections` and `cellForRow` accordingly

Comment: How to edit my cellForRowAt? I attached the code to first message

Comment: Yes, I just thought of it myself, thank you) And one more question how to make moving to a section in real time with animation?

Comment: This is another question.  There is an API to move items animated. First move the item in the data source then call this API.

Answer (score 1):

You can create 2 properties `completed` and `notCompleted` in the `Manager` and use them as *dataSource* of the `tableView`.

```
class Manager {    
    lazy var completed: [Task] = {
        return tasks.filter({ !$0.isCompleted })
    }()
    lazy var notCompleted: [Task] = {
        return tasks.filter({ $0.isCompleted })
    }()
}
```

`UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` methods,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return section == 0 ? manager.notCompleted.count : manager.completed.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return section == 0 ? "Todo" : "Completed"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want your original dataSource to be an array of the 2 different arrays (one with completed and one that is not completed.) `[[]]`

I found [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48877836/4757272) that seems pretty solid. However, it returns an dictionary, but i rewrote it slightly for you:

```
extension Sequence {
    func group<U: Hashable>(by key: (Iterator.Element) -> U) -> [[Iterator.Element]] {
        return Dictionary.init(grouping: self, by: key).map({$0.value})
    }
}
```

This way when you are in title header or `cellForRowAt` you can call it by `manager.task[indexPath.section][indexPath.item]`