# SwiftUI MapKit Annotation Optimisation

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mapkit, mkannotation

I am working on a project where SwiftUI and MapKit is used to draw annotations on a Map. The solution I have is able to draw about 1k annotations, but I need a solution that can handle at least 10k without lag or performance issues.
I have created a sample code that draws a red circle on a Map. You can add annotation by pressing the 'Add' button. There is also a tracker class that tracks number of times annotation is rendered.

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct MapAnnotation {
    var id: Int
    var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D
}

class Tracker {
    var done = 0
    static let shared = Tracker()
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var mapAnnotations: [MapAnnotation] = .init()
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Map() {
                ForEach(mapAnnotations, id: \.id) { intensity in
                    Annotation("", coordinate: intensity.location, content: {
                        Circle()
                            .foregroundStyle(Color.red)
                            .frame(width: getWidth(intensity: intensity))
                    })
                }
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                print("Adding")
                Tracker.shared.done = 0
                mapAnnotations.append(.init(id: .random(in: 0 ... Int.max), location: .init(latitude: .random(in: -5 ... 5), longitude: .random(in: -5 ... 5))))
            }, label: {
                Text("Add")
                    .font(.title)
                    .foregroundStyle(Color.red)
            })
        }
    }
    
    private func getWidth(intensity: MapAnnotation) -> CGFloat {
        Tracker.shared.done += 1
        print(Tracker.shared.done)
        return 10
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

Running the code (Xcode 15.1, iOS 17.2 SDK) above prints the following:

```
Adding
1
2
Adding
1
2
3
Adding
1
2
3
4
```

This indicates that whenever a new annotation is introduced, the system re-renders all previously existing annotations. Consequently, when handling a dataset of 5000 annotations and introducing an additional one, the entire set of 5001 annotations undergoes rendering, leading to lag and performance issues.
Is there any way to optimise annotation rendering to avoid performance issues?

Update:
Changed the code to add annotations in bulk:

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct MapAnnotation {
    var id: Int
    var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    // Other Data
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var mapAnnotations: [MapAnnotation] = .init()
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Map() {
                ForEach(mapAnnotations, id: \.id) { mapAnnotation in
                    Annotation("", coordinate: mapAnnotation.location, content: {
                        Circle()
                            .foregroundStyle(Color.red)
                            .frame(width: 10)
                    })
                }
            }
            
            VStack {
                Button(action: {
                    mapAnnotations.append(.init(id: .random(in: 0 ... Int.max), location: .init(latitude: .random(in: -5 ... 5), longitude: .random(in: -5 ... 5))))
                }, label: {
                    Text("Add One")
                        .font(.title)
                        .foregroundStyle(Color.red)
                })
                
                Button(action: {
                    for _ in 0 ... 999 {
                        mapAnnotations.append(.init(id: .random(in: 0 ... Int.max), location: .init(latitude: .random(in: -5 ... 5), longitude: .random(in: -5 ... 5))))
                    }
                }, label: {
                    Text("Add Many")
                        .font(.title)
                        .foregroundStyle(Color.red)
                })
            }
            .background(Color.black)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

I have profiled the new code in instruments and have found that following trend:

[image]

It shows that when 5k annotation are present, adding one more is taking about 27 seconds on main thread causing unresponsiveness.
Most of the time is spent inside MapKit `[MKAnnotationView _metricsDidChange]` and I doubt I can optimise that.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Use an ObservableObject so you can debounce you also want to use some kind of filtering so you only show what is actually on the screen.

Comment: Having profiled this with Instruments, the lag is not from SwiftUI. Most of the time is spent calling `[MKAnnotationView _metricsDidChange]`. I doubt there is anything you can do about that in SwiftUI. Try *lazily* showing annotations instead, and/or combine multiple annotations in the same area into one annotation, only separate them when zoomed in.

Comment: Yes, that's what I found in instruments. I was hoping for MapKit to somehow optimise them based on zoom level but don't think such is possible.

Comment: You have to optimize them yourself with SwiftUI

Comment: You could try a different approach using clustering, see for example:
 [Decluttering a Map](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkannotationview/decluttering_a_map_with_mapkit_annotation_clustering)
 
 and `MKClusterAnnotation`,
 "An annotation that groups two or more distinct annotations into a single entity."
 see: [MKClusterAnnotation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkclusterannotation)

Comment: In UIKit, there is a difference b/w annotations (the abstract object representing a geographic point) and annotation views (the visual representation of those annotations). We can add lots of annotation to a `MKMapView`, but the map will only instantiate annotation views for the small subset of annotations that would currently be visible (and if you turn on clustering, only a fraction of those). So, we add might add thousands of annotations, but that might result in only a dozen annotation views being instantiated at any given point. But a SwiftUI `Annotation is adding an annotation *view.*

Comment: But here, you are adding lots of annotation *views*, and, worse, without any clustering.

Comment: @Sweeper: How does this lazy rendering work?

Comment: @Rob: I have the same issue with SwiftUI on visionOS, where the Apple samples use the Annotations just like the OP used them. What is the best approach to include a clusterable MKMapView in a SwiftUI app, in a way that it is still behaving reactive, can cluster annotations and can handle thousands of annotations? I did not find any samples online that actually show this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I found this library now, which looks promising: https://github.com/vospennikov/ClusterMap

Comment: If that works for you, great. Personally, I'd do a `UIViewControllerRepresentable` of a view controller driving a `MKMapView`) and enjoy the native clustering built in to MapKit (e.g., judging from that screen snapshot, that library doesn't offer the same animations that MapKit does).

Comment: For those interested in comparative benchmarks, on a `MKMapView` using clustering with 5000 annotations, adding an single annotation took ~0.1 sec on an iPhone 13 Pro Max (release build). It actually was a bigger performance hit than I was expecting. And pinch-zooming becomes largely impractical with 5000 annotations (albeit, clustered down to a reasonable number), as it appears to be re-running the clustering logic for those 5000 annotations repeatedly during the pinch gesture.

Comment: FWIW, related post https://stackoverflow.com/a/69069768/1271826

Answer (score 0):

Cluster the annotations or draw a custom overlay.

ForEach looping all the items is normal and not intensive. Only the diff result is used to init new objects like a MKMapAnnotation if it is initing duplicate annotations then there could be an issue with the annotation identities.

FYI SwiftUI “does not render views provided by native platform frameworks (AppKit and UIKit) such as web views, media players, and some controls.” https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/imagerenderer

Comment: Clarification added