# Clustering annotation with SwiftUI iOS 17 without UIKit

Tags: swiftui, mapkit

I am using the new iOS 17 SwiftUI Map and want to display a huge number of POIs.
As it takes a lot of time to load I want to cluster them.
This answer seems to work only with UIKit and MKMapViewDelegate:

[Clustering annotation with swiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67959357/clustering-annotation-with-swiftui)

I haven't found any documentation about this so far.

Do I really need to write my own clustering algorithm and group the annotations?

```
import MapKit
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State
    var mapCameraPosition: MapCameraPosition = .region(MKCoordinateRegion(
        center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 43.64422936785126, longitude: 142.39329541313924),
        span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 1.5, longitudeDelta: 2)))

    var body: some View {
        Map(position: self.$mapCameraPosition) {
            ForEach(data) { s in

                Marker("", coordinate: s.coordinate)
            }
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

struct SampleData: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var latitude: Double
    var longitude: Double
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(
            latitude: latitude,
            longitude: longitude)
    }
}

var data = [
    SampleData(latitude: 43.70564024126748, longitude: 142.37968945214223),
    SampleData(latitude: 43.81257464206404, longitude: 142.82112322464369),
    SampleData(latitude: 43.38416585162576, longitude: 141.7252598737476),
    SampleData(latitude: 45.29168643283501, longitude: 141.95286751470724),
    SampleData(latitude: 45.49261392585982, longitude: 141.9343973160499),
    SampleData(latitude: 44.69825427301145, longitude: 141.91227845284203)
]

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: "Do I really need to write my own clustering algorithm and group the annotations?" No you don't. Just write a `UIViewRepresentable`. MapKit for SwiftUI doesn't have this feature yet.

Comment: Seems like this feature is no avalable on the new SwiftUI Map. Unfortunately I want to use it.
So what I found is using this package:

https://github.com/vospennikov/ClusterMap

Comment: @Sweeper: Unfortunately, this approach is not as straightforward as it seems, at least for someone who is not an expert in UIKit and SwiftUI. I tried to adapt an existing solution that was written in UIKit to SwiftUI, but failed. The map itself kinda worked, but getting it reactive and sending out events that I can work with does not seem to be trivial. I found the ClusterMap library via another blog post now and will try this one.